# MySQL returns me results no matter what I type! :(

Tags: mysql

I have a user table that has an auto increment userid field that I would like to use as a login ID. The format of the userid field is 1,2,3,4,5,..etc.

However when I do a select statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid='0001'
```

The above statement returns me the information for userid '1'. No matter how many '0' i put in front of the '1', I will always get the record for userid '1'

May I know how I might get it to return results only when it matches the exact userid (i.e., returns records for user with userid 1 when I type `userid=1` and not `userid=00000001)`?

I'm sorry if I didn't explain this clearly enough. I'm trying to pick up SQL by doing online tutorials and it's so frustrating :(

Comment: wow, thank you all for the quick response! I'll give it a whirl!

Answer (score 2):

If the ID is `int` please use this, also don't forget to wrap `user` with backticks as it's a reserved keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE userid=0001;
```

or this:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE userid=1;
```

As you have mentioned you need **EXACT** ID record.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up integer vs. string comparison. If your ID is INT, it is compared as integer (so the trailing zeros are omitted.)

Answer (score 2):

This is because your auto-increment is of type INT (NUMBER), and you are looking for string comparision (in SQL varchar)
You should make your column type as VARCHAR and use this statement

```
select * from user where userid like '0001'
```

OR

```
select * from user where userid like '%0001%'
```

Comment: When you make your search column as VARCHAR then this will impact your performance as STRING comparision is slower than INT comparison. So be careful before making your ID column as VARCHAR

Answer (score 2):

If the user ID is an `int`, this is expected behaviour (00001 = 1).

Making the ID a `varchar` field will help. However, this doesn't sound like a great idea.
Why do you want to allow `000001` next to `001`? It's bound to cause problems, with no discernible advantage (to me).

Either have an automatically incrementing ID (1 2 3 4 5 ....), or completely random strings generated when the user creates the record. The latter will make it impossible for people to guess other users' IDs which can be a good thing under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

USE `LIKE`::

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid LIKE '0001'
```

Answer (score 1):

the datatype of the column `userID` is `INT`. When you create a statement and has condition on `userID`, mysql implicitly cast it into `INT` that's why the string `0001` is equivalent to `1`.

Here's a suggestion you might want, change the data type of the `userID` into `VARCHAR` (*string*) and create an algorithm to increment the `userID`. *When the column is string, `0001` is not equal to `1`*.